# Maven - setup project from Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

On the maven Nexus all artifacts (including sources) are published, but can I also get the project from the Nexus so I can recompile the source code in my IDE? I need this to make a single change in the code but I can't find the source code anywhere on the internet, only the artifacts (including xyz-sources.jar) on the Nexus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projects are not stored in Nexus. If you are lucky, the pom contains the meta information of the git or svn path. Then you can checkout from there. Alternatively, you can use the pom and the unpacked sources to construct a compilable project (I may miss additional files and resources, though).

Comment: It worked! I extracted the -sources.jar, created dir src/main/java, put the code in there and moved the pom.xml from META-INF/maven/{package} into the root dir and it compiled successfully!